# PHPunit is not Asserting RuntimeException

Tags: php, phpunit

I am working with Symfony application in Docker container. For my Integration test case I am asserting an RuntimeException but PHPunit responds with

```
Failed asserting that exception of type "RuntimeException" is thrown.
```

My code that throws the exception

```
$result = $this->openSearchService->searchDocument($index, 1, $body);
if (empty($result)) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ExceptionMessageEnum::POST_NOT_FOUND);
}
```

My Test case that expects the exception

```
public function testInvalidPostId(): void
{
    $this->expectException(RuntimeException::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage(ExceptionMessageEnum::POST_NOT_FOUND);
    $this->getDeletePostRequest('123-456-789');
}
```

I have debug my code and exception is actually being thrown but PHPunit is not catching it.

Another thing is PHPUnit is catching the exception when I use `expectedException` annotation like this

```
/**
 * @expectedException RuntimeException
 */
public function testInvalidPostId(): void
{
    $this->getDeletePostRequest('123-456-789');
}
```

Comment: Wild guess : you probably have multiple classes called RuntimeException in your project (Phpunit alone contains several classes with that name in different namespaces). Could it be that you picked the wrong one in your test ?

Comment: Temporarily catch **any** exception (run that test in isolation) with a step-debugger, then double check the class-name of the exception matches **your** expectations. You have to argue with your own learning, not with Phpunit, which is just a stupid testing framework.

Comment: @Halibut That was my first guess. To be 100% sure I click on class name from both actual code and test case and my IDE navigated to the same class each time.
So I am sure importing the same `RuntimeException` class